# The gsutil tool is not working to register a channel in object change notification

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When executin the follow command:

```
gsutil notifyconfig watchbucket -i myapp-channel -t myapp-token https://myapp.appspot.com/gcsnotify gs://mybucket
```

I receive the follow answer, but I used the same command before in another buckets and it worked:

```
Watching bucket gs://mybucket/ with application URL https://myapp.appspot.com/gcsnotify...
Failure: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/mybucket/o/watch?alt=json returned "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://myapp.appspot.com/gcsnotify">.
```

I used gsutil config to set permissions and tried with gsutil config -e also.

I already tried to set the permissions, made myself owner of the project, but is not working, any help?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error. You must configure `gsutil` to [use a service account](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Using_Account) before you can watch a bucket.

Answer (score 2):

An additional security requirement was recently added for Object Change Notification. You must add your endpoint domain as a trusted domain on your cloud project. To do that, the domain first has to be whitelisted with the Google Webmaster Tools.

See instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorization

Comment: I tried that too, the domain is in the endpoint whitelist, but still receiving the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the bucket is part of the same project where it's whitelisted?

Comment: The bucket was not part of the same project, then now I tried to add the bucket to the project and the error still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I also determined that I needed to:

1. Whitelist my appspot domain
2. Create a service account before I can watch a bucket.

At first I was using the google cloud shell and I figured it should just be authenticated. `gsutil ls` listed the objects in my bucket so I assumed I was authenticated. However that is not the case.

You need to instal gsutil or [google cloud sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/), log in, get the .p12 file from the service account, and auth it as Wind Up Toy described. After that it will work.